# python-requests hook similar to pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION?

Tags: python, python-requests, pycurl

I've been utilizing PycURL for my project https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tidehunter which makes use of the `pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION` hook to consume incoming HTTP stream in a controllable way. Use cases can be found on the project page, or the technique like this:

```
def _on_data_receive(self, data):
    self.buffer += data

    if data.endswith('\r\n'):  # or any valid chunk delimiter
        # Do something about self.buffer
        print self.buffer

    if True:  # some valid condition to disconnect
        return -1  # the way to stop the stream, would raise pycurl.error
```

I'm considering switching out of PycURL as the solution I'm using to terminate stream on-demand is rather hacky (also happy to gain better solution for that use case with PycURL). Also `requests` is a much more pleasant library to use.

So is there anything in `requests` that I can leverage to achieve the same purpose? Or maybe it's also something like a incoming stream handler that I need to explore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks relevant (specifically the `iter_content` and `iter_lines` methods): http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow

Comment: Thanks @IsmailBadawi. I've explored http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-requests before and that was the solution I used. The decision to use `pycurl` instead was due to the write function hook's capability to `return -1` in order to terminate the stream based on custom condition.

Comment: [Event hooks](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=write%20function#event-hooks) maybe?

Comment: @woozyking: you can use `stream=True`, then read from `response.raw` and close that when done, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** 2016-03-22: Apologize for the selfishness.

#### Current Answer

The following snippet is what I applied to fully replace `pycurl` using `python-requests`. In short, simply supply with `stream=True` argument.

```
import requests

def tide_on(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, **kwargs)

    for line in r.iter_lines():
        # wish to stop after consuming just one line
        print(line)
        break

    r.close()
```

---

#### Previous "Answer"

The current version of `requests` at the time of speaking really made it easy to implement what I asked. Huge thanks to the team behind `requests`!

I fully replaced `PycURL` with `requests` in [`tidehunter`](https://github.com/woozyking/tidehunter) since version 1.0 and it's working great!

Thanks again to all the comments above :)

Comment: Please write how you solved it in the answer, so others can benefit too. This is not actually an answer to your question.

Comment: @Hjulle thanks for the advice. I've eventually come around to edit this with a more answer-like answer. Hope it helps more people than my previous selfish comment.